# How can I assign same private IP 10.3.3.51 to two azure vm having differnt MAC address? only one vm will be providing service at a time

Tags: networking, azure, load-balancing, high-availability, azure-networking

I have two vms behind the Azure Load balancer working as High availability that is only one vm is providing service at a time, other vm will be in passive state. I want to keep same IP address 10.3.3.51 on both VM how can I achieve that? health probe should send probe on 10.3.3.51 to the both VMs.

Comment: You can use something like [keepalived](https://keepalived.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html) to manage your vip, assigning it to whichever of your two nodes is active. Alternately, you can assign the vip to a load balancer that sits in front of your two vms.

Answer (score 0):

If your VMs are linux you can use `keepalived` to achieve what you want.

https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/keepalived-basics

Each VM has it's own IP address, but a separate `virtual_ipaddress` is configured that is initially bound to the master VM and if that one fails the backup VM takes it.